# android apk upload not working because name not valid

Tags: android, xamarin

I have signed and zipalign my android application and now wishes to upload it on the play store.
I however get the following message when I am done uploading it:

**Upload failed
Your APK's package name must be in the following format "com.example.myapp". It may contain letters (a-z), numbers, and underscores (_). It must start with a lowercase character. It must be 150 characters or fewer.**

My apk name is

**dd.afm.aftermath.apk**

So I don't understand why it does not comply?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the `packageName` in your manifest? (If you use gradle, it might be called `applicationId` in your `build.gradle` file)

Comment: are you using an IDE?if you are then how is the ide even letting you have the name?what is the name of your packages?Also I dont know if am geting this correctly,but the "dd.afm.aftermath.apk" doesnt meant your apk is"dd.afm.aftermath.apk.apk" right?

Answer (score 7):

Change your AdnroidManifest.xml file's package value from "AndroClient.AndroClient" to "com.example.myapp" (or whatever).

Then Xamarin will use it when compiling.

Answer (score 3):

The error message complains about the 'package name', not about the APK file name.

Your package name is set to 'AndroClient.AndroClient', which does not match the prescribed pattern of com.example.app. Change your package name to something like `com.dualdub.androclient`.

**background**

The package name and version code is what identifies an app. Increase the version code, while keeping the same package name, and people will get automatically updated to the new version. Change the package name and the Google Play Store considers it a different app.

As you probably know, there are now millions of published apps. To prevent package name clashes the prescribed way is to prefix your app's name with your website domain in reverse. In your profile it says that http://dualdub.com is your website. So you should prefix your app's name with "com.dualdub.". Package names are case-sensitive; it is common practice to use all lower case.

Google Play Store reads your package name from the AndroidManifest.xml, from the 'manifest' element; 'package' attribute. How to change that depends on your IDE.

**Change package name with Android Studio**

When you are using Android Studio you are also using the Gradle build system. The Gradle build system overrides the package name in the manifest for you. During the build it puts the `applicationId` in the manifest package attribute.

Open the build.gradle file in your app module. It should be located at: `<projectDir>/app/build.gradle`. It should look something like this:

**app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.appname"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Update the applicationId to be `com.dualdub.androclient`.

**Change package name with Eclipse**

To be honest, I have never used Eclipse so I will have to give you vague directions.

In the AndroidManifest.xml you have the manifest package attribute. It plays a dual role: 1) it specifies the package name (also known as the applicationId), 2) it helps shorten class names that you specify with other elements, e.g. when specifying activities you can write `android:name=".MainActivity"` instead of `android:name="com.example.appname.MainActivity"`.

To change the package name you will actually have to change the namespace of your code. In your .java files change the first line from 'package AndroClient.AanroClient;' to `package com.dualdub.androclient;`.

Most likely, Eclipse will have a refactoring tool to rename java packages to make this easier for you.

Comment: I use Android Studio 3.0.0 beta 6.  The Gradle build system does NOT override the package name in AndroidManifest.xml.  My app/build.gradle contained the correct ApplicationId, starting "com.me...", while the manifest said package = "14".  (No idea where it got that.)  The build failed, complaining'14' was no good as a package name because it isn't a Java identifier.  Changing the manifest to match gradle fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As the error says:

> **It must start with a lowercase character**

While your package name is: *AndroClient.AndroClient*, which starts with an **upper case** letter.

---

Citing from the documentation:

> Package Name is the package namespace for your app (following the same rules as packages in the Java programming language). Your package name must be unique across all packages installed on the Android system. For this reason, it's generally best if you use a name that begins with the reverse domain name of your organization or publisher entity. For this project, you can use something like "com.example.myfirstapp." However, you cannot publish your app on Google Play using the "com.example" namespace.

I'd suggest to just conform to the "reverse domain" rule of thumb

Answer (score 0):

its the problem of your package..
Change your package name as remove example from it..
eg:

```
com.developer.name
```

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your java source probably has the package name.

```
package com.gosylvester.hilbilyfashliegt;
```

The package name is also in the manifest.
The app name or what you call the app is setup in the manifest for android:label

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gosylvester.hilbilyfashliegt"
    android:versionCode="7"
    android:versionName="Juger" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.gosylvester.hilbilyfashliegt.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Generally you would store the app name in the res/values/strings.xml below app_name is the app name.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Hil Bily FashLiegt</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Make stays</string>
    <string name="author" translatable="false">by cousin Dan</string>
    <string name="new_this_version">""New this one.  Stil Kant make wir catch stay on good.  Toch screen to mak er on.  Use make stays for duk tap wird"</string>
    <string name="aboutcheckbox">Reckon not show this here agin</string>
    <string name="shareText">I reckon this here hillbile fashliegt app is worth a jar of moonshine. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gosylvester.hilbilyfashliegt</string>
    <string name="sharesubject">Android add free flashLight App by Dan Sylvester</string>
    <string name="about_firstrun">com.gosylvester.hilbilyfashliegt.firstrunabout</string>
    <string name="preferences">com.gosylvester.hilbilyfashliegt.prefrences</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: I am not using java, but xamarin. It does not change anything though. Here is my manifest: <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="AndroClient.AndroClient" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0.1">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
  <application android:label="Aftermath Beta" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:largeHeap="true" android:debuggable="false" android:name="mono.android.app.Application"> What apk name should I use?

Comment: Sorry I can't help you.  I should learn one of these run anywhere kits but I haven't.  I did add a tag for you though.

Comment: The fact it's xamarin is irrelevant. Does the name need to match exactly the package name of the application ?

Comment: IDK it could be different with xamarin but the tag will get someone to help.